# Error with my random number generation code

Tags: python

My code it generates a random number it checks if it is in the list if it is it generates another random number and then it checks if it is equal or not and shows the result and repeats the process. But when I start the code it generated the normal number but it repeats the numbers and it shouldn't repeat the number. What do I do?

```py
from random import randint
import os

n = 0
numsort = 14564487
attempt = 0
numbers = []

while n < 100:
    num = randint(10000000, 99999999)
    if num in numbers:
      num = randint(10000000, 99999999)
      numbers.append(num)
    attempt += 1
    if num == numsort:
        print(f'{num}' + '\033[32m' + ' Right number' + '\033[0m')
        print(f'After {attempt} attempts it was')
        break
    if num != numsort:
        print(f'{num}' + '\033[31m' + ' Wrong number' + '\033[0m')
        print(f'Attempt # {attempt}')
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Because you only store the number in `numbers` if it is already in `numbers`, which of course it will never be.  The `numbers.append` line needs to be un-indented one tab.

Comment: Of course, the odds of getting a match in 100 tries are 1 in 900,000, so you're not likely to see it..

Comment: despite the low odds, the first `if` statement should probably be a `while` statement as well

Comment: anyway this should be closed. I am not helping cracking code

Comment: `random.sample(range(10**7, 10**8), k=100)`

Comment: @TimRoberts Except this isn't going over 100 tries, is it? The loop variable is never updated so the loop is infinite. Therefore, the probability of collisions is 1.

Comment: There are many things about this code that do not make any sense. Please try to think about the logic of the code yourself; and read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and carefully study what happens when the code runs. Among many peculiarities: the code has an outer loop that says `while n < 100:`. **What part of the code is expected to cause `n` to change**? If the goal is to make an infinite loop to `break` out of, then why write it this way? What is supposed to be special about the number `100`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a simple one. The primary problem is with this code snippet:

```
num = randint(10000000, 99999999)
if num in numbers:
    num = randint(10000000, 99999999)
    numbers.append(num)
```

Translating this to English, we have:

1. Generate a random seven-digit integer
2. If the integer is in our list of numbers then regenerate it and add it to the list

The problem you have here is that you have no guarantee that the regenerated number won't also be in the list. The chance of this happening will grow as the list grows. And, since your loop variable is never updated, this list will grow infinitely.

To fix this problem, you have two possible solutions. For small lists, you can continue on with your strategy of regenerating numbers and replace the if with a while:

```
num = randint(1000000, 9999999)
while num in numbers:
    num = randint(1000000, 999999999)
numbers.append(num)
```

Note that this will only work while the desired size of your list is much smaller than the range of possible values being generated. As you fill up the list, the chance of collisions between the range of possible values and actual values will increase, causing the while loop to run longer.

Alternatively, you can use `sample` to choose your values, which would replace the entire loop:

```
numbers = random.sample(range(1000000, 10000000), n)
```

Note here that the use of `range` means that this is actually just as space efficient as the previous solution and will guarantee unique values.